# Ruby on rails running multiple apps one server and ip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache2, passenger

I own my own testing sever and was wondering how you would go about hosting two apps with two different domains names that they are linked to. I am using passenger with apache2.

At this point I need to keep the code separate for each app, as a proof of concept.  I have the first on set up with these settings in the conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName website.camp
    ServerAlias www.website.camp
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/ruby/app_name/public
    RailsEnv development
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory "/home/ruby/app_name/public">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And I am not sure if this is at all a good idea.  Any opinions and comments would be much appreciated.

Comment: The `VirtualHost` directive is how you do this, you just need to declare more than one and check with `apachectl -S` that they're loaded properly. As a note, this should be on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/). Also, don't run your server in `development` mode. That's going to be brutally slow. If you need cheap DNS names use [xip.io](http://xip.io) for your local addresses.

Comment: Thanks, so just kick my rails dev=ENV over to production? then.  I mean I haven't seen any problems this far but it would be nice to avoid them in the future. (server is has two 2.93 ghz processors and over 50g of ram so far) And I will move these questions over to the other forum.

Comment: The `development` mode is a special case where everything in `app/` is reloaded on each request. This is great if you're altering code constantly, but not so great if you're trying to do in-depth testing.

Comment: Thanks again, I passed this on right away to another dev that asked about slowness in his app, a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

The `virtual host` directive was the answer I was looking for.